# ogr SetPrecision doesn't work

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr

I'm creating a shapefile with a field type of real, but I want to lower the standard precision from 15 decimal places to 10, here is my code:

```
dst_filename = "Polygonized.shp"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_filename )      
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer("layer", geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon )   

fd = ogr.FieldDefn( str(Polygonize_Field_Name), ogr.OFTReal )

fd.SetPrecision(10)
dst_layer.CreateField( fd )                
gdal.FPolygonize( band,band1, dst_layer,0, [], callback=None )
dst_ds = None
```

(I'm also polygonizing, but that works fine.)

When I go to open up the file and return the precision using:

```
ds = ogr.Open("Polygonized.shp")
lyr = ds.GetLayer()
lyr_dfn = lyr.GetLayerDefn()
lyr_fld = lyr_dfn.GetFieldDefn(0)
lyr_fld.GetPrecision()
```

It clearly returns a precision of 15.

Am I doing something wrong when specifying the precision?

Comment: Having the same issue.  Did you ever resolve?

Comment: Unfortunately I never managed to resolve this, I believe it was due to how shapefiles work and the .DBF file not accepting varying precision.